# Close datepicker once second click on specified button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Good Afternoon,

So I have `ui-datapicker` here, with hidden date field and image button with id attribute `#trigger`. After click datepicker come up as it supposed to but if I click the same button again, I need this datepicker to dissapear.

```
$(function() {
$('#datepicker').datepicker();
$('#trigger').click(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('show');
});
});
```

This is the code which assign show attribute to the datepicker.
But I do struggle with `hide` functionality there.

Any ideas/suggestions please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> You can implement a function to do it or you can just add on the click event.

function calHide({$("#mycalendar").datepicker("destroy");$("#mycalendar").hide()};

function calShow(){$("#mycalendar").show();$("#mycalendar").datepicker();};

Comment: I dont get how can I merge this with the code I have given above.
If I do it like in this codepen https://codepen.io/myhub4/pen/ZMNapo
it does work once and then showing errors in the browser debug.

Comment: Try to use this example
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</body>
</html>

Comment: this isn't working @Mr Milk displaying false. Calendar in my script is hidden as default. On button click #trigger it does come up. and on click at the same button #trigger should hide. Your suggestions at the moment didn't worked unfortunately.

Comment: check this out I did implement a button to open and close calendar there are 3 calendars look that, I think the last one is related to your case:  https://codepen.io/_Milk/pen/MqdOxz

Comment: yup, I can see it is working in your example, however not in my script. Can that be because state of my callendar is hidden by default so first click have to open it?

Comment: Look that once again! Notice. The elements must have to be loaded before to render de main function in this case.

Comment: Just to clarify, in your example mentioned above your calendar should display after the page is rendered, so be careful might you are getting an error before to render the calendar. Would you mind to share your html and the javascript you are loading.

Comment: Still the same, second click on the picture doesnt close the datapicker so we are where we where on the first post here.

Comment: Now I understand what you want. Look that, I'm sorry but your implementation is not the correct one try to use this example, It is the same from Jquery's page https://codepen.io/_Milk/pen/bxyLZp Try to click on icon.

Comment: Mr Milk, no offence but this have to work with my scripts, I know about the showOn and button arguments but this wont work in my scenario.

That is why I need to do it via either js or jquery to open and close by random element on the site not one generated by jquery.

Comment: Ok. look I just isolate in Js file the script, https://codepen.io/_Milk/pen/bxyLZp no offence, but the point is your script is not working and it will never work what you are trying to do is create and destroy in the same function, look the new example and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is here:

```
$(function() {
$('#trigger').click(function () {
if ($(this).hasClass('opened')) {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('hide');
} else {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('show');
}
$(this).toggleClass('opened');
});
});
```

PS. Thank you Mr Milk for all your effort and time.